# WCF - Preserving Object References in WCF (IIS Hosted)

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, serialization

I am getting the

> 'Object graph for type
>   'MyCompany.MyEntity' contains cycles
>   and cannot be serialized if reference
>   tracking is disabled.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

when calling the service with an object that contains references to other object (those are essentially linq to sql entities).

I am reading this which explains how to enable preserving references for this case in the self hoseted service environment: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx

However, my service has to be hosted on IIS. How to enable the service to serialize the entites correctly?

Comment: The answer is right in the article you linked. Read the whole thing.

Comment: @John, it's even easier than I thought and certainly easier what's in the article: I just used this [DataContract(IsReference=true)]

Comment: add an answer for that and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @John - done, posted in the answer what helped me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even easier than I thought and certainly easier what's in the article: I just used this [DataContract(IsReference=true)] to fix the issue.